# MSbuild command won't create web deploy package but Visual Studio IDE can

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, webdeploy

I've tried several different commands and versions of MSBuild but I still can't generate a Web deploy package from it. I can, however, create one via Visual Studio 2017 using the same solution and pubxml file.

What I have tried:

I must be missing something in command line but I don't know what. Below are the commands I have tried:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:PublishProfile=<location of pubxml file>
/p:PackageLocation=<where to put zip>
/T:Package
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package
```

and various combinations of those with MSBuild versions from .Net 4.5, VS2017, and VS2015.

Comment: And what specifically does *can't generate* mean? Do you get error messages? What are those messages? Something happens, and without that information we can't possibly help you. If you don't understand why, call your auto repair shop and say *I have a Ford. It doesn't work. What's wrong?* and see if they can help without any more information.

Comment: There's no error.  it does the precompile for the web site and then nothing else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> MSbuild command won't create web deploy package but Visual Studio IDE can

The type of project you are deploying should be the `WebSite`. The publish process of website project is not plumbed into the build process. When you create a publish profile in VS the following are created:

1) A publish profile (.pubxml file) under App_Data/PublishProfiles.

2) A **website.publishproj** in the root of the website.

The purpose of the website.publishproj is to facilitate command line publishing. So **publish file should be website.publishproj rather than WebSite1.sln file**. So the publish command line should be:

```
msbuild.exe "website.publishproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:PackageLocation="D:\LocalServer\web1.zip" /T:Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
```

[image]

After that, you will noticed MSBuild created web deploy package to the `PackageLocation`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent many hours looking for this info.

Comment: What if the .publishproj file doesn't exist?

Comment: 6.5 years later, your answer is still helping to save computers from being thrown out windows!